# My overrided method not working properly, code goes into method, but not execute

Tags: java, android, android-espresso, android-testing

I writing autotests for application. On the start of application it has an onboarding (ViewPager) with some pages and button on the last page. I need to swipe these pages and press the button. This is my class for onboarding

```
public class Onboarding {

ViewInteraction onboardingScreen = onView(
        allOf(withId(R.id.vp_onboarder_pager),
                childAtPosition(
                        allOf(withId(R.id.cl_onboarder),
                                childAtPosition(
                                        withId(android.R.id.content),
                                        0)),
                        0),
                isDisplayed()));

ViewInteraction skipButton = onView(allOf(withId(R.id.btn_finish)));

ViewAction skipOnboardingScreen = new ViewAction() {
    @Override
    public Matcher<View> getConstraints() {
        return any(View.class);
    }

    @Override
    public String getDescription() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void perform(UiController uiController, View view) {
        ViewPager onboardingPager = (ViewPager) view;
        OnboarderAdapter adapter = (OnboarderAdapter) onboardingPager.getAdapter();
        int currentPage = 0;
        int screenCount = adapter.getCount();
        while (screenCount > 0){
            onboardingPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage);
            screenCount--;
            currentPage++;
        }
        skipButton.perform(click());
    }
};

public void skipOnboarding() {
       onboardingScreen.perform(skipOnboardingScreen); 
}
```

I call my test in this way:

```
@Test
public void onboardingPass() {

    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Onboarding onboarding = new Onboarding();
    onboarding.skipOnboarding();

}
```

When test executing, `onboardingPager.setCurrentItem(currentPage)` must switch current page, but it does not. When I saw it in debuger, test execute this line, but pages does not switching. Why it can be? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> ... I need to swipe these pages ...

To **swipe** in your instrumentation tests use this with your view;

```
onboardingScreen.perform(swipeRight());
```

**swipeRight()** is from [AndroidX Test](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4m2yYSTdvIg) package androidx.test.espresso.action.ViewActions.swipeRight

Read more about the AndroidX Test Espresso ViewActions package [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/espresso/action/package-summary.html).

Setup the swipes as per your requirement and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to scroll to the last page of your `ViewPager`, then you should use [ViewPagerActions.scrollToLast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/test/espresso/contrib/ViewPagerActions.html#scrollToLast()) instead. And I'm sure that they can all be reduced to as simple as:

```
public void skipOnboarding() {
    onView(withId(R.id.vp_onboarder_pager)).perform(ViewPagerActions.scrollToLast());
    onView(withId(R.id.btn_finish)).perform(click());
}
```